# How to get the current max-workers value?

Tags: gradle

In my `build.gradle` script, I have an `Exec` task to start a multithreaded process, and I would like to limit the number of threads in the process to the value of max-workers, which can be specified on the command line with `--max-workers`, or in gradle.properties with `org.gradle.workers.max`, and possibly other ways. How should I get this value to then pass on to my process?

I have already tried reading the org.gradle.workers.max property, but that property doesn't exist if it is not set by the user and instead max-workers is defined by some other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to access this value using API [`project.getGradle()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getGradle--) [`.getStartParameter()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html#getStartParameter--) [`.getMaxWorkerCount()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#getMaxWorkerCount--).

Comment: Appears to work. I tested it with the default (number of CPUs), with the command line option `--max-workers`, and with the property `org.gradle.workers.max` defined in gradle.properties.